# How to mark measures?

Tags: wood

I'm not a very contentious person. One of the most basic things I struggle with in all types of home improvements is how to properly mark measurements. Two examples, to mark the x/y position for a screw on the wall or properly mark where to cut a bolt that is too long. I try to use angle iron, spirit, and folding rule and mark it as closely as possible, but usually, I end up with a few millimeters off. Is there a good method to improve acc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They say, "measure twice, cut once". So check your measurements a few times before you commit.

If you're drilling into a wall, make a large cross mark so that you know if you've wandered off the precise point you wanted to drill into.

If you've trying to hit the exact middle of something, measure in from both sides. For example, if you wanted to find the middle of a 1384mm space, don't bother with pesky math. Find a round number near half of that (700mm) and mark from both sides. Your actual center is in the middle of your two marks, and you can probably figure that by eye.

Double check what you're measuring against. If you have a board with an end that isn't 90 degrees, your marked length will vary according to where your tape sits. Same for walls -- there are lumps and bumps that will throw your measurements off.

Cheap tape measures and rules can be inaccurate. Be sure to understand how yours is or isn't.

Don't make additive errors. If you have to make repeated steps of 17-3/8", don't mark 17-3/8" from the last mark. Do 17-3/8", 34-3/4", 52-1/8", etc.

Use the right pencil for the job. When you need precision, a small (0.7mm) mechanical pencil is far better than a carpenter's pencil.

My last thought is about perspective: sometimes it's okay to be a couple of mm off. Almost nobody will notice. However, there are times when you have to be perfect. Knowing the difference between the two is golden.

Comment: Well spoken and helpful!

Comment: Great input! Any hints on how to address bumpy walls? (Totally agree on the last point, my next project is stuccos though and there the precistion is very important.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren -- Can you be specific about what aspect of bumpy walls is giving you problems?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only a few ml off, then I'd say you're doing pretty good for a beginner DIY.

For bolts and edges on boards I have always found combination square a very handy tool to have. (See picture below)

The X/Y on a wall gets a little trickier. You need a good tape measure, one that's at least 1" wide so it doesn't have a tendency to bend. Get into the practice of measuring from both sides of the wall and from ceiling to floor from your "point". Then measure again. Make sure you use a sharp pencil to mark your cut or drill point.

Like everything else, this takes practice. good luck.

[image]

Comment: And make sure to cut on the waste side of the line.

Comment: @SolarMike I’ve watched “teams” of finish carpenters measure and cut trim up high on scaffolding. One will measure and shout down “66 7/8” strong” (or weak) which indicates to the other which side of the line to cut. It’s fascinating to watch.

Comment: @LeeSam  I've watched them too but they  shout 66 7/8+  or 66 7/8 -.  They were awesome to watch. I think it's the hardest trade.